# How can the derivation of the energy of an electron in a Fermi gas using the Heisenberg uncertainty principle be made rigorous?

Tags: electrons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

When modeling a large number of non-interacting identical fermions in a potential well of volume $V$ as a harmonic oscillator and assuming the Pauli exclusion principle, it is easily seen that the average fermion energy is at least of the order

$$\left<E\right> = \frac{\hbar^2}m\left(\frac{n}V\right)^{\frac23}$$

where $n$ is the number of Fermions and $m$ is their mass.

The same order of magnitude is obtained when we reason as follows: if the volume if $V$, then each fermion has a space of the order of size $V/n$ to itself, so $\Delta x\sim\left(\frac Vn\right)^{1/3}$ for each one of them. Invoking the Heisenberg uncertainty relation

$$\Delta x\Delta p\ge\frac\hbar2$$

we get

$$\Delta p\gtrsim \hbar\left(\frac{n}V\right)^{\frac13}$$

so that the average kinetic energy is at least

$$\left<E\right> = \frac{\Delta p^2}{2m} \gtrsim \frac{\hbar^2}m\left(\frac{n}V\right)^{\frac23}$$

However, there is one step in this derivation which I don't know how to justify: how does it follow from the fact that the fermions are confined to a volume $V$ that $\Delta x\sim\left(\frac Vn\right)^{1/3}$? In principle each of the fermions could have a wavefunction that is supported on the whole volume, as long as they are all different (or at most as many repetitions as there are spin states). Is there a straightforward way to see from the Pauli exclusion principle, without actually going back to a harmonic potential and our knowledge of its solutions, that the uncertainty in position of each fermion can be at most of the order $\Delta x\sim\left(\frac Vn\right)^{1/3}$?

Answer (score 1):

The expected energy derived from the uncertainty principle makes sense but not really rigorous. Unlike the >= relation you wrote above, the result is (hbar)^2*(n/V)^(2/3)/(8m) which is 1/8 of the expected order. The idea here is to use the uncertainty in spacing to approximate the momentum and then calculate the energy. The reason people usually use the uncertainty principle to make an approximation is, statistically, as long as the number is large and the event is natural, then a Gaussian distribution in probability is likely to appear, and for a pure Gaussian distribution (the wave function), Heisenberg uncertainty principle can mathematically takes the equal sign, and gives you a precise answer. Under weak external field, fermi gas is relatively stable, and thus the approximation is usually valid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I find the part where we go from ∆x to the estimation of the average energy plausible enough, my doubt is about how we can justify the upper bound on ∆x as $(V/n)^{1/3}$